# Display grid on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a pixel art maker using jQuery that allows the user to choose a grid size of his or her liking (view its [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VQRrgQ)). However, I would like to have a 25 x 25 cell grid appear immediately on page load, which I achieved in another version of the same project that uses vanilla JavaScript ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MQRxJZ)).

What would be the best way to do the same for my jQuery version? (Below is the code for the function (`makeGrid(e)`) that I'd need to edit.)

In the vanilla JS version, I was able to do so by simply calling `makeGrid(25, 25);` despite its lack of parameters, which baffles me.

```
$('.size-picker').submit(function makeGrid(e) {
  // preventDefault() method intercepts 'submit' event, which would normally submit the form and cause the page to refresh, preventing makeGrid() function from being processed
  e.preventDefault();
  // if grid is already present, clears any cells that have been filled in
  $('table tr').remove();
  // grid height value entered by user
  const heightInput = $('.input-height').val();
  // grid width value entered by user
  const widthInput = $('.input-width').val();
  // outer for loop adds desired number of rows (grid height)
  for (let i = 1; i <= heightInput; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    // inner loop adds desired number of columns as cells (td) within rows (tr) and creates a class called 'Cell' for each cell (td). Class is used later, allowing user to color cells on click
    for (let j = 1; j <= widthInput; j++) {
      // ':last' is a jQuery extension (not part of CSS specification) that selects a single element by filtering the current jQuery collection and matching the last element within it. For best performance using ':last', first select element(s) using pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":last")
      $('tr').filter(':last').append('<td></td>');
      // here, .attr() method sets attribute (class) to name provided as second argument for matched elements (td)
      $('td').attr('class', 'Cell');
    }
    $(document).add('p')
  }
  // fills in cell with chosen color when mouse button is pressed down over it. Unlike function dragColor(), doesn't require mouse to enter a cell while mouse button is being held down. Note: 'mousedown' event is fired when the mouse button is pressed but before it's released, whereas click event is fired after mousedown (click) and mouseup (release) events have completed
  $('.Cell').mousedown(function() {
  // adds chosen color to cell upon a click event. Selector 'this' refers to cell (with class 'Cell') being clicked. Variable 'color' is defined here rather than globally so JS checks whether a new color has been picked before each mousedown event
    let color = $('.color-picker').val();
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
  });
  dragColor();
});
```

Comment: Please check CodePen now @ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWzjOZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your makeGrid function so that it's declared separately.

Inside that function, make sure `e` is defined before calling `preventDefault()` on it.

Then add:

```
$(window).on('load', makeGrid);
```

Updated Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLJvGM